# Приём email писем

Tags: node.js, email

Я хочу с помощью node.js реализовать сервер для приёма писем.

У меня есть машина с ip к которому уже привязан домен - (Напр. **domain.com**).

И я хочу, чтобы если кто-то отправит письмо на адресс **name@domain.com** - мой сервер в консоле (для начала) показал бы тему и текст этого сообщения.

Есть ли простой способ для этого, как например с тем же http ты создаёшь сервер с определённым портом - сделав запрос на **domain.com** в консоле спокойно выводишь всё, что тебе нужно.

P.S. У меня была даже тупая идея реализовать почтовый сервер через модуль http, но конечно-же это не сработало. Код прикреплю снизу...

---

index.js

```
const async  = require('async');
const http   = require('http');
const config = require('./config');

async.each(config.server.ports, createServer);

function createServer (port) {
  http
    .createServer((...args) => serverHandler(port, ...args))
    .listen(port, () => console.log('Server Started & Listen Port', port))
}

function serverHandler (port, req, res) {
  res.end('Hello World!');

  console.log(port, req, '\n\n\n\n')
}
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  server: {
    ports: [25, 465, 587, 2525]
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы MX запись в DNS добавили?

Comment: Я использую vds сервер. И на хостинге моего домена я прописал эти записи
1) ns1.zomro.net; 
2) ns2.zomro.ru; 
3) ns3.zomro.com; 
4) ns4.zomro.su; 

Вы думаете, что мой код правильный и дело в vds?

Comment: Входящая почта передается по протоколу SMTP. и этот протокол с HTTP ничего общего не имеет. Так что вам надо реализовывать для начала этот протокол (или найти где нибудь готовую реализацию). А потом вас ждем еще масса развлечений по декодированию почтовых сообщений.

Comment: А после этого все таки прописать MX запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что там всё так просто. Я бы рекомендовал что-нибудь готовое, вроде [smtp-server](https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server).

И, насколько я знаю, вам ещё нужно MX DNS записи добавить.

Comment: Я использую vds сервер. И на хостинге моего домена я прописал эти записи 1) ns1.zomro.net; 2) ns2.zomro.ru; 3) ns3.zomro.com; 4) ns4.zomro.su;